# Abelianization of limit groups

Tags: gr.group-theory, geometric-group-theory

Let $G_1$ and $G_2$ be limit groups, and let $C_1$ and $C_2$ be cyclic subgroups of $G_1$ and $G_2$, respectively.

Question:

If $G$ is the amalgamated product of $G_1$ and $G_2$ with amalgamated subgroups $C_1$
and $C_2$, is it true that $d(G) = d(G/G^{'})$?

Notation: $d(G)$ is the minimum number of generators for the group $G$.

Comment: How are $C$ and $C_1$ meant to be used here? I would edit to be $C_1$ and $C_2$, but I'm not sure what you want to do with them. I hope I haven't already changed what you meant about amalgamated subgroups, just that it wasn't clear what was happening there.

Comment: The title is a bit misleading if $G$ is not assumed to be itself a limit group.

Comment: $G_1$ and $G_2$ have subgroups $C$ and $C_1$? This is reminiscent of the well-known particle $m$ with mass $p$.

Answer (score 4):

Here's a silly counter-example (though I doubt this is what you have in mind). Take $G_1=G_2=\mathbb{Z}$ with $C_1=2\mathbb{Z}$ and $C_2=3\mathbb{Z}$.  Certainly $G_1,G_2$ are limit groups. Then

$G=\mathbb{Z}*_{2\mathbb{Z}=3\mathbb{Z}}\mathbb{Z}$

the fundamental group of the trefoil knot complement. This is easily seen to have abelianization $\mathbb{Z}$, but of course is not itself cyclic.

In this example, $G$ is not itself a limit group.  There are also counterexamples in which it is. For instance, consider $G_1=G_2=F_2$, the free group of rank two, and let $C_1=C_2=\langle w\rangle$ be any maximal cyclic subgroup which is not a free factor but is non-trivial in homology (for instance $\langle a^2ba^{-1}b^{-1}\rangle$).  Then the corresponding double

$G=G_1*_{C_1=C_2} G_2$

has abelianization of rank three, but is itself of rank four. This latter estimate is tricky to prove, however, and I'm not sure if it can be deduced from anything in the literature. You should look at the *oeuvres* of Louder and Weidmann for an idea of how to prove it.

**Added:**

In an e-mail, Richard Weidmann has pointed out the following easy way to prove that $d(G)=4$: quotient out by $w$ to note that $G$ surjects the free product

$F_2/\langle\langle w\rangle\rangle*F_2/\langle\langle w\rangle\rangle$ ;

this has rank 4 by Grushko's theorem, so $G$ does too.

Comment: Thanks Mr. Henry Wilton, where I can find that article or book oeuvres of Louder and Weidmann?

Comment: I mean, look at the papers authored (independently) by Louder and Weidmann.  For instance: R. Weidmann, 'The Nielsen method for groups acting on trees'.
*Proc. London Math. Soc. (3)* 85 (2002), no. 1, 93–118; or L. Louder,
'Scott complexity and adjoining roots to finitely generated groups',
*Groups Geom. Dyn.* 7 (2013), no. 2, 451–474.